# Tkinter not displaying output when called in another script

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I have 2 python scripts gui.py and main_file.py. I am trying to call gui.get_names() function in main_file.py script. A box pops up, where I input my name and click the submit button but nothing gets printed in the console. However, gui.py script works perfectly fine. I think there is some mistake in main_file.py script. Please have a look at the code and suggest necessary changes.

[image]

**gui.py**

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
input_frame = Frame(root)
input_frame.grid(padx=10, pady=10)


def get_name():
    return ent1.get()


input_frame = Frame(root)
input_frame.grid(padx=10, pady=10)
name_label = Label(input_frame, text='Name: ')
name_label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=(0, 10))

ent1 = Entry(input_frame, width=18, textvariable=StringVar())
ent1.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=(0, 10))
ent1.focus()

button_frame = Frame(root)
button_frame.grid(sticky="EW")
button_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
bt1 = Button(button_frame, text="Submit", command=get_name)
bt1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="EW")
root.mainloop()
```

**main_file.py**

```
import gui


def main():
    name = gui.get_name()
    print(name)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: `ent1 = Entry(input_frame, width=18, textvariable=StringVar())` argument `textvariable` should be a variable. so try saying `var1 = StringVar()` and `ent1 = Entry(input_frame, width=18, textvariable=var1)` not sure if thats the mistake tho

Comment: `main()` will only be executed after the window (created when importing gui) is closed because of the `mainloop()` in the gui.py.  However, when `main()` is executed after the window is closed, `gui.get_name()` will raise exception due to the entry is destroyed.

Comment: @acw1668 But how to resolve this issue, Can you suggest a way to tackle this problem?

Comment: What is the purpose of `main_file.py`? As you said `gui.py` itself can do what you want.

Comment: @acw1668 This is just a sample code, Basic idea is user should fill required  info in GUI and press the submit button. Thereafter the main function should get executed.